# SVG filter simulate blending mode

Tags: css, svg, filter, svg-filters

I'm trying to simulate `mix-blend-mode:exclusion` blending mode with only SVG filters. The docs say exclusion is a substraction of darker color from lighter, in other words, greater color component value minus smaller color component value.
Is there any way to simulate this logic using SVG filters?
The original image is:

[image]

The filtered image would be:

[image]

The color to exclude is `#3a0339`

I'm bringing some code snippets for your convenience:

```css
svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.myFilter {
  filter: url(#myFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg>
<defs>
<filter id="myFilter" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
  <feFlood result="fill" flood-color="#3a0339" flood-opacity="1">
  </feFlood>
<feComposite operator="arithmetic" in="SourceGraphic" in2="fill" k1="0" k2="0.5" k3="0.5" k4="0"/>
 </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
<img class="myFilter" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux2FT.png">
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can get close by combining two feBlends (screen and multiply), but the final composition requires one be subtracted from the other. And I don't think there is a way to subtract two colours without zeroing out the alpha channel.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau so all calculations actually involve alpha channel same way other channels are processed?

Comment: To subtract them, you would need to use `feComposite`, but that also subtracts the alphas, so they cancel out (ie. 1-1=0). Leaving you with an invisible result.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau But there's a way to extract alpha channel? Using 'feFuncA' or 'SourceAlpha'. If I could somehow zro out alpha after extraction and then add it back later?

Comment: That doesn't work. Filter primitive results are premultiplied. So if you zero out the alpha, the colour components get zeroed as well. It doesn't matter anyway, I have found a solution,See my answer.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thank you man! Excellent work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Filter Effects module](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#feBlendElement) updated the definition of `<feBlend>`.  In addition to the values of `mode` defined in the SVG 1.1 spec, you can now use all of the extra modes defined by the [Compositing and Blending specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#blendingseparable).

That includes "exclusion", so as long as you are in a browser environment, you can actually do what you want quite easily.  The following works in Firefox and Chrome. I haven't checked any other browsers.

```css
svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.myFilter {
  filter: url(#myFilter);
}
.myFilter2 {
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}
.mix-bg {
  background-color: #3a0339;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mix-bg IMG {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="myFilter" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-color="#3a0339" result="flood"/>
      <feBlend mode="exclusion" in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img class="myFilter" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux2FT.png">

<div class="mix-bg">
  <img class="myFilter2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux2FT.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Credit goes to @AmeliaBR for reminding me of this change.