# SVG filter apply filter only to opaque region

Tags: css, svg, filter, svg-filters

Lets have a filter applied to an image with transparency. I need to have this filter applied only to opaque region, in other words, I guess, where alpha is non-zero. You can see in the example currently transparent region is filled with flood color. Would that be possible?

```css
svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.myFilter {
  filter: url(#myFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="myFilter" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-color="#3a0339" result="flood"/>
      <feBlend mode="exclusion" in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img class="myFilter" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png">
```

Comment: feBlend does not support "exclusion" - only normal, multiply, screen, lighten & darken. (You can also mimic hard light and soft light with more work )

Comment: @MichaelMullany it actually does, you can run example yourself. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991821/svg-filter-simulate-blending-mode

Comment: Yes - this was news to me! Great to see more of the Filters 1.0 spec make it into browsers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `feComposite` node to apply the alpha channel of the source graphic to the output of the `flood` filter:

```css
svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.myFilter {
  filter: url(#myFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="myFilter" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-color="#3a0339" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="flood_alpha"/>
      <feBlend mode="exclusion" in="flood_alpha" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img class="myFilter" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png">
```

Comment: I also think you mean "feComposite" node not feBlend node since that's what's in the code you wrote - edited the answer to reflect that.  In SVG 1.1 - feBlend does not support "exclusion" - only normal, multiply, screen, lighten & darken. Other modes are being added as part of the Web Filters 1.0 spec. but it's not cross browser yet.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Sorry, yes. My mistake.